# How to approve comments from a user with previously approved comments

Tags: users, comments, workbench

WordPress has a useful option for comment moderation in its [Discussion Settings](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Discussion_Screen) panel called "Before a comment appears: Comment author must have a previously approved comment".

[image: screenshot]

How can one configure Drupal to approve future comments if a user has a previously approved comment in the site?

This is a follow-up from an unresolved post on Drupal.org: [Auto-publish comments after that anonymous user’s previous comments have been approved [X] number of times](http://drupal.org/node/710302)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a small custom module. In D6 you override hook_comment:

```
function MYMODULE_comment(&$comment, $op) {
    if ($op=='insert' && !$comment['uid'] && $comment['status']==COMMENT_NOT_PUBLISHED){ //only perform on operating  insert for new comments and if the user is anonymous
        // query database for a previously approved comment by this email
       $has_published=db_result(db_query("SELECT cid FROM {comments} WHERE status=%d AND mail='%s'", COMMENT_PUBLISHED, $comment['mail']));  
       if ($has_published){
          db_query("UPDATE {comments} SET status=%d WHERE cid=%d",COMMENT_PUBLISHED,$comment['cid']); //set the current comment to unpublished
          $comment['status']=COMMENT_PUBLISHED; //return with a status of not published so the user is notified that their comment is  awaiting approval
       }
    }
}
```

It should be easy to convert this to D7 using [hook_comment_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_insert/7).

[The solution was originally suggested here](http://lists.drupal.org/pipermail/support/2009-November/013428.html).

Comment: Looks great! This would be a good idea for a contributed module.

Comment: Would it be possible to update the answer for current Drupal 7 ?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have programming skills use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Comment: Yeah, the [thread on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/710302) recommended using [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules).

Comment: How would you do that using Rules ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Comment Trust](https://www.drupal.org/project/comment_trust) module (Drupal 7 only) in order to **auto-approve** comments from **trusted** visitors.

> Comment Trust auto-approves comments by users with previously-approved
>   comments. It rewards trusted commenters with immediate approvals,
>   while requiring you to approve the comments by new visitors. Works for
>   both anonymous and authenticated users.